# WinForms Textbox Autocomplete events

Tags: .net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have a .NET TextBox with AutoComplete feature on the form. The form has also `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton` defined. If I try to commit a suggestion with `Enter` key or close drop down with `Esc`, my form closes.

My idea is to create my custom textbox inheriting from `TexBox` and capture `Enter` key and the `Escape` key, but only when the autocomplete UI is visible. How could I know when the autocomplete list is visible?

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (IsOnAutoComplete())
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Enter || keyData == Keys.Return)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

In other words, do you know how could I implement `IsOnAutoComplete()` method? Has the textbox any **events** to notice this?

Any other solution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What messages are you receving on MyTextBox WndProc method when the autocomplete list is displayed ? Maybe you can capture that messages

Comment: Actually this is my question :-)

Comment: Do you receive a WM_CREATE (0x0001) message ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution I have used in the past is removing the Accept and Cancel button associations when the text box has focus.

```
    textBox1.Enter += (o, args) =>
                                    {
                                        AcceptButton = null;
                                        CancelButton = null;
                                    };
    textBox1.Leave += (o, args) =>
                                    {
                                        AcceptButton = btnOK;
                                        CancelButton = btnCancel;
                                    };
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to give a generic solution to the problem. You need to implement this in all your forms that have textboxes with autoComplete. My intention is implement it at the Textbox level, being a generic solution. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: So you put the exact same functionality in a custom text box.  Override OnEnter and OnLeave - to backup/restore the buttons on the form hosting it.